# Get two different keywords from map

Tags: clojure

I just started learning Clojure and I'd like to get two keywords from a vector of maps.

Let's say there's a vector

```
(def a [{:id 1, :description "bla", :amount 12, :type "A", :other "x"} {:id 2, :description "blabla", :amount 10, :type "B", :other "y"}])
```

And I'd like to get a new vector

```
[{"bla" 12} {"blabla" 10}]
```

How can I do that??
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `mapv` to map over the source vector. Within the transform function you can destructure each map to extract the keys you want and construct the result:

```
(mapv (fn [{:keys [description amount]}] {description amount}) a)
```

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you want the `:description` and `:amount` separately, not maps that map one to the other, you can use [`juxt`](https://www.conj.io/store/v1/org.clojure/clojure/1.8.0/clj/clojure.core/juxt) to retrieve both at the same time:

```
(mapv (juxt :description :amount) a)
;; => [["bla" 12] ["blabla" 10]]
```

If you actually did mean to make maps, you can use for instance `apply` and `hash-map` to do that:

```
(mapv #(apply hash-map ((juxt :description :amount) %)) a)
;; => [{"bla" 12} {"blabla" 10}]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
(mapv #(hash-map (:description %) (:amount %)) a)
```